# request-reply scope versus request-reponse exchange pattern

Tags: mule, messaging

I am trying to understand a use case for the [request-reply scope](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Request-Reply+Scope) when would this be preferred over [request-response exchange pattern](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/VM+Transport+Reference) ?, especially if the underlying transport is JMS, I am guessing using the exchange pattern or the scope will do exactly the same things internally and functionally from a flow perspective.

There are a few hassles that crop up with using request-reply scope around maintaining the correlation id and replyTo properties details [here](http://ricston.com/blog/usecase-explaining-behaviour-requestreply-block/) and [here](http://ricston.com/blog/correlation-id-propagation-flows/) , will the same challenges exist if one use a request-response exchange pattern ? (I am guess yes, can someone confirm please)

Basically when to use request-reply over the request-response exchange pattern

**Updating my question to further probe into the behavior of request-reply scope.**

To experiment use of request-reply scope in the first use case mentioned in the accepted answer.

Use Case 1

> The endpoint itself does not support request-reponse and still you
>   want to simulate synchronicity

I created a flow like below, I have tested this without the message property transformer too (same behavior)

[image: Request-reply use case]

The actual behviour is that the request waits for ever, even after the file is successfully written, the reply never comes into the outbound VM

My flow code is as below

```
<flow name="request-replyflowtest">
        <http:listener config-ref="Orders_HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/rr" doc:name="request-reply-test"/>
        <set-payload value="Hello world" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <message-properties-transformer overwrite="true" doc:name="Message Properties" >
            <add-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" value="vm://back"/>
             <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\sudarshan.sreenivasan\Desktop" outputPattern="hello.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="back" doc:name="VM"/>
        </request-reply>
         <logger message="response not written out" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="This is from a different flow" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you should go for request-response in most of the cases except in the cases where:

- The endpoint itself does not support request-reponse and still you want to simulate synchronicity
- You want to send a request to one kind of transport and expect reponse on a differnt one, i.e: send to jms expect response in amqp
- You want to send a request to one connector and expect reponse on a differnt one, i.e: send to jms connector a expect response jms connector b

Comment: Thanks, sounds logical, can you please give an example for "The endpoint itself does not support request-reponse and still you want to simulate synchronicity" ?

Comment: MQTT could be an example. Certain TCP protocols even FILE.

Comment: Possible Light bulb moment -- In case we use a File outbound in the request phase within a request-response scope, it would not invoke the response phase until the entire file write has been completed ? also would mule take care of maintaining the correlation id in the messages ?

Comment: Do you mean a request-reply? No, the inbound endpoint of the reply part will always be working. Around correlation Mule will take care if it's possible, otherwise you might need to set a expression-message-info-mapping element.

Comment: Yes sorry I mean request-reply -- i will try out the file example and then ask you to confirm my understanding... Thanks

Comment: I have tried a sample to work out the first use case you pointed, it does not work as expected, can you please have a look at it.